# Cannot run multiple kubectl commands using Azure Devops Pipeline Kubernetes@1 task

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to run multiple kubectl commands using Kubernetes@1 task in Azure Devops Pipeline, however I am not sure how to do this.

`kubectl exec $(kubectl get pods -l app=deployment_label -o custom-columns=:metadata.name --namespace=some_name_space) --namespace=some_namespace -- some command`

Comment: Please post expected output.

Comment: Hi, how the things going now? Dose my explanation and the work around could give you any help? If yes, you can [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) thus other SO users will be able to see whether the solution works. If you are still facing some issues please leave a comment so we can continue to help you .

Answer (score 4):

If what you want is input these multiple commands into `Command` parameter of the task:

[image]

Unfortunately to say, No, the task script does not support this compiled method until now.

As the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/kubernetes?view=azure-devops#commands) described:

[image]

The command input accept **only** **one** of these commands, which means you can only input one command in each `Kubernetes@1` task.

Also, if you want to input instead of select one of commands from it, it could not exceed the range of commands allowed by this task and has restrict writing format like this:

[image]

For the commands you provided, if continue want to use `Kubernetes@1` task, you'd better split these commands into the separate one with multiple tasks. You could check this [blog](https://colinsalmcorner.com/devops-with-kubernetes-and-vsts-part-2/) for detailed usage.

---

As work around, if you still want to execute this multiple commands at same time, you can use [Azure CLI task](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureCLIV1/Readme.md)(if you are connecting Azure K8s), or use [Command line task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)(if what you are connecting is the local k8s server).